# cambiar color de una forma en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy teniendo problemas para lograr cambiar un rectángulo de color ya que la función
'configure' no tiene la función 'fill'. Se podría crear otro rectángulo pero no es una forma viable ya que se generarían demasiados al apretar repetidas veces el botón.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class GUI():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cuenta = 0
        ventana = tk.Tk()
        ventana.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

        ancho = ventana.winfo_screenmmwidth()
        altura = ventana.winfo_screenheight()
        Botonsalida = Button(ventana, text='salida', command=ventana.destroy)
        self.Bandeja1 = Canvas(ventana, height=altura, width=ancho)
        Botonprueba = Button(ventana, text='prueba', command=self.prenderyapagar)
        self.Bandeja1.create_rectangle(2, 10, 100, 40, fill='white')
        Botonprueba.place(relx=0.95, rely=0.45, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.05)
        Botonsalida.place(relx=0.95, rely=0.95, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.05)
        self.Bandeja1.place (relx=0.38, rely=0.55, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.07)

        ventana.mainloop()

    def prenderyapagar(self):
        self.cuenta = self.cuenta + 1
        self.Bandeja1.configure(fill='blue')


        if self.cuenta == 2:
            self.cuenta = 0
            self.Bandeja1.configure(fill='white')

GUI()
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Si lo que quieres es cambiar el color del rectángulo que creaste adentro del canvas entonces primero hay que asignar ese rectángulo a una variable

```
self._rectangulo = self.Bandeja1.create_rectangle(2, 10, 100, 40, fill='white')
```

**Nota:** No sé si quieras que sea de uso interno de la clase o no, la declaré con el prefijo `_` para denotar que es un atributo interno de la clase.

En tu función debes acceder a ese rectángulo a través de `itemconfig`:

```
self.Bandeja1.itemconfig(self._rectangulo, fill='green')
```

Si lo que deseas es cambiar el fondo del canvas entonces debes utilizar el argumento `bg` (Del inglés background):

```
self.Bandeja1.configure(bg='blue')
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class GUI():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cuenta = 0
        ventana = tk.Tk()
        ventana.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

        ancho = ventana.winfo_screenmmwidth()
        altura = ventana.winfo_screenheight()
        Botonsalida = Button(ventana, text='salida', command=ventana.destroy)
        self.Bandeja1 = Canvas(ventana, height=altura, width=ancho)
        Botonprueba = Button(ventana, text='prueba', command=self.prenderyapagar)
        self._rectangulo = self.Bandeja1.create_rectangle(2, 10, 100, 40, fill='white')
        Botonprueba.place(relx=0.95, rely=0.45, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.05)
        Botonsalida.place(relx=0.95, rely=0.95, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.05)
        self.Bandeja1.place (relx=0.38, rely=0.55, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.07)

        ventana.mainloop()

    def prenderyapagar(self):
        self.cuenta = self.cuenta + 1
        self.Bandeja1.configure(bg='blue')
        self.Bandeja1.itemconfig(self._rectangulo, fill='green')


        if self.cuenta == 2:
            self.cuenta = 0
            self.Bandeja1.configure(bg='white')
            self.Bandeja1.itemconfig(self._rectangulo, fill='red')

GUI()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que en la traducción no se distingue si el problema es el color o qué quierquieras cambiar el atributo color una vez ya lo definiste o lo dibujaste tu quieres cambiar atributos de un objeto dentro del canvas y para ello primero debes seleccionar el objeto con el mouse y con un método find que debe tener tkinter localizar el objeto específico.  Canvas va haciendo cada objeto y le pone una numeración.  Con ese numero puedes cambiar un atributo de cada objeto dibujando por el canvas.

En TCL buscar el objeto se pueda por las coordenadas x y y del mouse, o por el nombre del tag del objeto o por una ventana x1 y1 x2 y2 donde este encerrado el objeto seleccionado. En python debe ser un método del canvas que sea find wittag o current y ese método devuelve un número entero generalmente. Que corresponde al objeto del canvas y a ese objeto si le puedes cambiar los atributos con configure o con itemconfigure, porqué hay objetos cuyos atributos se deben  cambiar con itemconfigure como las imágenes.